# Cell reference based on FOR loop index

Tags: excel, vba

Here is some of my code:

```
Dim wbX As Workbook
Dim wbY As Workbook
Set wbX = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Converter\aaa.xls")
Set wbY = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Converter\bbb.xlsx")

For i = 1 To wbX.Sheets.Count
wbY.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("Y" & i + 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i + 2).Formula = "=RIGHT(("S" & i + 2); 4)"
```

The problem is that ("S" & i + 2) is not recognized as a cell - VBA spits out syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression `"Y" & i + 2` does not yield a valid cell reference because you concatenate a number to a string. You must convert the numeric expression to a string:

```
"Y" & Str(i + 2)
```

What I understand from your comment, the assignment should be written as:

```
"=LEFT(S" & Trim(Str(i + 2)) & "; 4)"    ' yields e.g.: =LEFT(S3; 4)
```

(The LEFT function gets the *first* characters from a string. This assumes the cells you reference contains strings, or that VB converts the value to a string first. And here you must use `Trim(Str(i + 2))` because you are constructing a string to place as a formula in the cell.)

Comment: ("Y" & i + 2) is recognized fine - VBA selects the correct cell. The problem appears when I insert ("S" & i + 2) into the RIGHT function. Then ("S" & i + 2) is no longer recognized as a cell. FYI the correct syntax for the RIGHT function is "=RIGHT(your cell; 4)"

Comment: I don't think you understand this correctly. For i = 1 To wbX.Sheets.Count counts the number worksheets in file ("C:\Converter\aaa.xls"). ("Y" & i + 2) selects cell Y + number based on the number of sheets in wbX + 2. If the number of sheets in wbX is equal to 10 the ("Y" & i + 2) part will select Y3 then Y4, then Y5 ... all the way to Y13. I want the last four characters of Y3, Y4, Y5... to appear in S3, S4, S5 etc. The catch here is that I don't want this to be a formula - it has to be a value.

Comment: Still nothing. I copied your code and I still get an error :(

Comment: "an error" sounds a little vague. What error? Did you check the resulting formula?

Comment: Application-defined or object-defined error. The ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i + 2).Formula = "=RIGHT(S" & Trim(Str(i + 2)) & "; 4)" line is highlighted. I'm getting no formula. VBA stops before inserting anything into the Y cells.

Comment: Dantee, you must learn some debugging. At this point you manually enter the formula in the cell to see what the correct formula is. Then you make the VB equivalent to put a hard-coded version of the formula in the cell, then you make in VB a string of the formula you want and inspect if you made that string correctly. If that all works, then you put that in your VB code, and now it _must_ be correct by virtue of the preceding procedure.

Comment: instead of just .Formula can you use formulaR1C1 for a test and see if it works?

Comment: Paul, it turns out that you were right. My friend helped me out and we used ActiveSheet.Range("Y" & i + 2).Formula = "=RIGHT(S" & Trim(Str(i + 2)) & ", 4)" which works. Thatnk's to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim rngC As Range
    For Each rngC In Range("C2:C100")
        rngC.Offset(0, 4) = Right(rngC, 4)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm a beginner so I was hoping for someone to modify my code a bit.